# Insert from php into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, email, hash

I've created an mail server with `dovecot postfix and mysql`.
The user should be able to create a new mail adress via a `php webpage` which will insert the data into the `mysql database`.
It also does insert it into the DB, but the connection to the mail server wont work with that credentials. 
When I insert the same things myself sirectly into the DB it works, can you please give that code a look and tell me what might be wrong?
I think it has something todo with the `password hash generation with doveadm`.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    if( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ){
            header("Location: home.php");
    }
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    $error = false;

    if ( isset($_POST['btn-signup']) ) {

            // clean user inputs to prevent sql injections
            $name = trim($_POST['name']);
            $name = strip_tags($name);
            $name = htmlspecialchars($name);

            $email = trim($_POST['email']);
            $email = strip_tags($email);
            $email = htmlspecialchars($email);

            $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
            $pass = strip_tags($pass);
            $pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);

            // basic name validation
            if (empty($name)) {
                    $error = true;
                    $nameError = "Please enter your full name.";
            } else if (strlen($name) < 3) {
                    $error = true;
                    $nameError = "Name must have atleat 3 characters.";
            } else {
                    // check email exist or not
                    $query = "SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username='$name'";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
                    if($count!=0){
                            $error = true;
                            $nameError = "Benutzeraccount existiert schon.";
                    }
            }

            //basic email validation
            if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
                    $error = true;
                    $emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";
            } else {
                    // check email exist or not
                    $query = "SELECT resetmail FROM accounts WHERE resetmail='$email'";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
                    if($count!=0){
                            $error = true;
                            $emailError = "Kontakt E-Mail Adresse bereits in Verwendung.";
                    }
            }
            // password validation
            if (empty($pass)){
                    $error = true;
                    $passError = "Please enter password.";
            } else if(strlen($pass) < 6) {
                    $error = true;
                    $passError = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
            }

            // password encrypt using SHA256();
            $password = shell_exec('/usr/bin/doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT -p '. $pass);


            // if there's no error, continue to signup
            if( !$error ) {

                    $query = "INSERT INTO accounts(username,domain,at,complete,resetmail,password,quota,enabled,sendonly) VALUES('$name','chillihorse.de','@','test','$email','$password','2048','1','0')";

                    $res = mysql_query($query);


                    if ($res) {
                            $errTyp = "success";
                            $errMSG = "Successfully registered, you may login now";
                            unset($name);
                            unset($email);
                            unset($pass);
                    } else {
                            $errTyp = "danger";
                            $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";
                    }

            }


    }
?>
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: Instead of printing a useless error message here `$errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";` change it to `$errMSG = mysql_error();` then you will see if/what is really failing

Comment: Changed it to "$errMSG = mysql_error();" But now there are no more error printed out

Comment: What are the advantages of mysqli?

Comment: Mitigation against SQL Injection attacks if you use it correctly by using Parameterised queries with bound variables

Comment: `if( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" )` that for one thing, is failing you since it's a false positive; you need to use 2 separate conditions.